# Two versions of the same class (1 static and one non static)

Tags: java, static

I want to have **2** versions of a class in my jar file:

- version 1: all the class variables have to be static
- version 2: ... without having them statically

Looking for good ways to deal with this; regarding maintenance for example.

My current solution is to copy the class after i changed something and overwrite the other one with the copy and changing the variable type.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: That sounds like a very broken design / requirement.

Comment: Why not just have one class and a static instance of that class?

Comment: The reason for the static class is that it is used as a base class for a lot of cucumber scripts, it has things inside like the drivers etc.

The non static version is used for testNG Scripts so that they can actually run in parallel

Comment: Show us what you have tried and an example of what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a simple answer to this. Like:

```
public interface Foo {
  public String bar();
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {
  @Override
  public String bar() {  ...
}

public class StaticFoo  {
  private final static Foo foo = new FooImpl();
  public static String bar() {  return foo.bar() };
}
```

In other words: you implement your "non-static" solution as your "base". Then you create **another** class that provides all the required methods in a **static** manor, relying on the *already existing* implementation to avoid code duplication.

For the record: this is still an **ugly** solution. I would rather step back and look at the problem you intend to solve with that. But the above is still something you *could* use. And of course: it works with **methods**, but I hope for your sanity that you are not doing OO programming and rely on using **fields** within classes. OOP is about behavior (methods), not state (fields).

(and it is *ugly* because you can't put down `StaticFoo implements Foo` ... because you would want to make all those methods *static* to meet your strange requirement). In order to improve that; this here would be a little bit nicer:

```
public class StaticFooProvider {
  public final static Foo = new FooImpl();
}
```

in the sense that it provides a single, static instance of that service interface to you; on which you can now call methods in a non-static way.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, i implemented it in the code. I tought on a other way to do it while implementing this. Create getters and setters for the variable and have one static variable that says if it is running in static or normal mode. (I didnt impent this becouse i hope that i can get rid of the static stuff soon)

Comment: You got my upvote for understanding that *static* is evil ;-)